# Avoid scraping of duplicate / clone / master-slave targets in Prometheus?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, high-availability

You have an clustered app called A, and it has two instances: A1 and A2.
This app is working is failover mode, so only one is the leader. They both expose metrics, but to actually have correct metrics you need to scrape only one of these apps. If you scrape both, you end up with much more complex Prometheus queries - always grouping by instance and then max(), to use just one.

Isn't there a way to specify in Prometheus job config that some of the targets are clones / duplicates / master-slave / HA-pair nodes - so that Prometheus scrapes only one of these nodes at the time, not all.

If there is no such feature, do you have some ideas how to solve this problem? Or you have already solved it... tell me how :)

I guess I'm not the only one who prefers having more elegant Prometheus queries.

Thanks in advance, Davor

Answer (score 0):

The same HA mechanics used for active-passive setup should be used for scraping. Just point Prometheus to the same HTTP balancer (LVS, or whatever you are using for active-passive setup). This will ensure only the *active* instance get scraped.

Comment: This is not advisable, as for example counters will appear to reset when the active target changes.

Comment: depends actually on the type nodes you have - clones or master / slave.

In my case the milan's proposal is actually good, because I'm running two nodes of the same app which are doing the exact same thing - they are clones. They pulling data from some external source and calculating some metrics. So they actually have the same data. I'm running two just for HA purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You should scrape both, and then use PromQL to choose which values to take based on which is currently leader. See the last paragraph of https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/#deployment